# парсинг списка html в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как лучше из такого списка:

```
<ul>
    <li><b>Штрих-код</b> <span>4810948005595</span></li>
    <li><b>Страна</b> <span>БЕЛАРУСЬ</span></li>
    <li><b>В наличии</b> <span>13 шт.</span></li>
</ul>
```

cоздать словарь на питоне?
Cейчас делаю так:

```
html = """
    <ul>
        <li><b>Штрих-код</b> <span>4810948005595</span></li>
        <li><b>Страна</b> <span>БЕЛАРУСЬ</span></li>
        <li><b>В наличии</b> <span>13 шт.</span></li>
    </ul>
"""

soup = Soup(html, 'html.parser')
desc = soup.select("ul li")
about= {}
for el in desc:
    about[el.find("b").text] = el.find("span").text
print(about)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ul>
    <li><b>Штрих-код</b> <span>4811530000325</span></li>
    <li><b>Страна</b> <span>БЕЛАРУСЬ</span></li>
    <li><b>В наличии</b> <span>1 шт.</span></li>
</ul>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Словарь можно сгенерировать с помощью dict comprehension:

```
my_dict = {i.find('b').text: i.find('span').text for i in soup.find_all('li')}
```

тогда в `my_dict`:

```
>>> my_dict
{'Штрих-код': '4811530000325', 'Страна': 'БЕЛАРУСЬ', 'В наличии': '1 шт.'}
```

Comment: совсем забыл что кроме генератора списка есть еще генераторы для словарей и множеств